# Can Google +1 icon be customized?

Tags: api, google-plus-one

Can I use my custom icon with Google +1 or I'm obliged to use one of the icons provided by Google? If I can, how?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm imagining your options are [pretty limited](http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/) regarding the amount of customization. But, you may be able to re-write the `plusone.js` file, although it depends how much work you'd like to invest for a different icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can since the +1 API is not public (at the time of writing this).

You can however configure the button looks here:

http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/

Also, you can try to figure out the +1 script and see if you can hack something:

https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use custom icon for Google +1 button.
Here is the link to the rules https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines#plusone-button