# Before/After Custom Google Plus One (+1) Images

Tags: javascript, css, api, google-plus-one

I know it's possible to edit the image div using the ID tag (#___plusone_0) but I am not sure if it's possible to set the before click and after click/+1 of this. Does anyone know? Couldn't find anything in the API.

Comment: Yes this is what I think I was asking. This is an old question asked many months ago, not sure if things have changed but I'll look into it.

Comment: What he said.  Beyond that, consider making sure you're not violating Google's TOS by altering the button.

Comment: @Bonjour What does that mean, to set the click?

Comment: As in setting the CSS (mainly image/bg) between the Pre and Post click state. I don't think this can be done. At the time, the button was pretty terrible but now they've improved it to match standard dimensions so this isn't really an issue anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is pretty well covered already:

[Can Google +1 icon be customized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738755/can-google-1-icon-be-customized)

---

**Consensus:** Unless you want to hack and breach terms, you shouldn't (but might be able to)